# Why is python changing this string literal to a unicode string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

It seems as though python is changing my key_s string into unicode, and I don't know why. I don't remember this being the normal behavior. If I type the lines manually in the interpreter, I don't have to convert them to strings first. I am not used to `"` or `'` indicating unicode but rather strings. Did something change I'm unaware of? Or does it have something to do with pycharm?

```
key_s = "time_delta"
print("key_s type:", type(key_s))
key_s = str(key_s)
print("key_s type:", type(key_s))
```

stdout when running `python program.py`

```
key_s type: <type 'unicode'>
key_s type: <type 'str'>
```

stdout from interpreter when typing `key_s = "time_delta"; print("key_s type:", type(key_s))`

```
key_s type: <type 'str'>
```

It defaults to str here, the behavior I would expect when I run the program. What gives?

I made a quick test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
# encoding: utf-8
print (type('123'))
```

outputs: `<type 'str'>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an encoding declaration at the top of the file? `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

Comment: There is. But deleting it, saving, and re-running doesn't change anything. Should it?

Comment: Show us code that, when run *exactly as posted*, demonstrates the problem, along with the *exact output* of running the *exact code posted*. The code you've posted is clearly missing things; for example, it's using Python 3-style `print` syntax and (supposedly) getting Python 3-like output without a `future` statement.

Comment: Also, why the heck are you using the `-u` flag in the `type('123')` test? This suggests that you might be using the [`-U` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-U) to run your other code, which is a flag you shouldn't use that would make all string literals default to unicode, pretty much exactly like you're seeing.

Comment: are you using a future import? like `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: (`-U` is literally documented under "Options you shouldn’t use", because you shouldn't use it.)

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't realize that was a category of cmdline options for Python. You win my internet for today. Hilarious.

Comment: I was trying to use the -u tag to see if that affected the result. But still doesn't